# wxPython hide() function with variable value

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm writing my first python app with wxpython gui and I was wondering if there is some simple way to pass a variable value to `hide()` function?

My variable keeps track of last viewed panel name and in some cases Id like to hide the last panel viewed

so in short

```
"self.lastpanel".Hide()
```

and the `self.lastpanel` value is in string format if it makes difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are asking how to access an attribute when the attribute name is a string, you need to use `getattr`

```
self.some_panel = wx.WidgetOfSomeSort(...)    
self.last_panel = "some_panel"    
the_actual_panel = getattr(self,self.last_panel)
the_actual_panel.Hide()
```